# Disable duplicate check for apex class?

Tags: apex, duplicate-management

Is there a way to disable the duplicate check for an apex class?

I have an insert of contacts, where I have a custom duplicate check. Now I would like to disable the standard duplicate check for only that apex class.

Comment: What is this 'standard' duplicate check?

Comment: The data.com duplicate management

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you can bypass duplicate check with DMLOptions.DuplicateRuleHeader Class: [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm#apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader)

Sample:

```
Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true; 
Account duplicateAccount = new Account(Name='dupe'); 
Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(duplicateAccount, dml); 
if (sr.isSuccess()) {   
 System.debug('Duplicate account has been inserted in Salesforce!'); 
}
```

Comment: Amazing! It works. Would you mind to share the code from the site in your answer? If one day the link will be down, your answer wont be helpful for others. Thank you really much.

Comment: Glad that it helped. I've updated the answer with the sample code.

Comment: Tried the similar code in trigger and it does not work. Does anybody know about any limitations in trigger context?

Comment: Do you add this apex code into the apex class in scope or do you create a separate apex class?

Answer (score 8):

Apparently the AllowSave only works if the duplicate rule is an Alert rule, not a Block rule.

> When you try to save a record that’s identified as a duplicate record
> by a duplicate rule, you’ll receive a duplicate error. If the
> duplicate rule contains the **Allow** action, an attempt will be made to
> bypass the error.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DuplicateError.htm#apex_class_Database_DuplicateError)

Comment: @ Ratan the above isn't what I'd consider a link only answer. He's provided a link to the reference documentation where the user can find further information about his answer.

Comment: Didn't have enough cred to add a comment.