# How to surpass/ignore Duplicate Management Rules in Apex?

Tags: apex, duplicate-management

I have activated the standard Duplicate Management Rule on Contact to prevent duplicate records.

When I try to create duplicate Contact records form SalsesForce side, it shows me a warning message and allows me to ignores the alert and create a duplicate record.

But when I try to create a duplicate record in Apex, it gives me an exception.

How can I surpass/ignore such alerts and create duplicate records in Apex?

Kindly help me out.

Comment: See this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78670/disable-duplicate-check-for-apex-class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

User the [DuplicateRuleHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm#apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader) of the DmlOptions class. The example in the documentation looks like this:

```
Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.runAsCurrentUser = true; 
Account duplicateAccount = new Account(Name='dupe');
Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(duplicateAccount, dml); 
if (sr.isSuccess()) {   
  System.debug('Duplicate account has been inserted in Salesforce!'); 
}
```