# How to check for duplicates while creating a record via Salesforce API

Tags: rest-api, leads

I have a usecase where users need to create Lead via Salesforce API. The use case is when user tries to create lead, the system checks if the lead or contact already exists with the same information. If it does not exist already, only then it should create a lead in salesforce.

I can think of writing an apex code if it was web to lead form, but I am trying to understand how to achieve it using an API.

Comment: see duplicate management feature

Answer (score 1):

I suggest defining your duplicate criteria using the Setup Menu's "Duplicate Rule" and "Matching Rule" options.   Are your users using a visualforce page to create the Lead?  If so, your apex controller could use Database.SaveResult for the DML which would allow you to check and handle duplicate errors by checking for `Database.DuplicateError` as shown in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm#apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult

Update:  You mentioned not using visualforce, therefore it seems appropriate to do this within a separate Apex Class and call that somewhere within your execution stack, `before insert`

Comment: no they won't be using visualforce to create the lead. But the Salesforce API, maybe using POSTMAN or curl.

Comment: I looked into duplicate rule but it only allows me to choose one object. Is there a way I can choose both lead and contact objects because it needs to search in both objects for duplicates.

Comment: You would need two duplicate rules. One for Lead.  One for Contact.

Comment: Sometimes the standard Duplicate Rules are 'good-enough', more on those here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_standard_rules.htm&type=5 and here is a helpful topic as well: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199477/how-to-surpass-ignore-duplicate-management-rules-in-apex (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm)

Comment: Please help me understand how can I write two duplicate rules?  I want when a new lead is created, it checks in the system if the same name exists in Lead or contact and based on that detects the duplicates. How do I make it work with two different conditions?

Comment: The standard duplicate rules that you can define in the Setup Menu act on 1 object.  That is Lead Duplicate Rules will check against Leads based on your Match Criteria, and act accordingly (warn, or block, etc) based on your Duplicate Rule.  I have seen some businesses use the Standard Lead Duplicate Rule,   and the Standard Contact Duplicate Rule.  Once activated, a Lead might not complain upon creation but might complain upon Lead Conversion since Lead Conversion essentially attempts to create a Contact in which case Contact Duplicate Rule runs.  If it helps we can bring this to a chat room.

Comment: The standard dupe rules act on 1 object.  Active Dupe Rules can warn/prevent creation of a single object based on same object. Try activating Contact Duplicate Rule(s). Since both Lead and Contact are "people" it makes sense to check both tables. For this, without code, recall that standard Lead Conversion 
 natively attempts to create a Contact from the Lead, so will trigger your Contact Matching Rules and Contact Duplicate Rule(s)s which can warn or block the creation of Contact, however Declarative Duplicate Rules cannot cross obj match. Does this help?